# How to Update the Screen after delete request in flutter?

Tags: flutter

how I can update the screen after a delete request. the delete request sent successfully and the item was deleted from the db ,the screen still showing the item but when I refresh the screen the item is gone. I tried to setstate but still not working .
I have created a costume widget (card) then I called this widget in another screen with future builder ;

```
     class APPOINTMENTItem extends StatelessWidget {
      final String doctor;
      final String date;
      final String id;
          APPOINTMENTItem(this.date, this.doctor, this.id);
         final APPOINTMENTData APPOINTMENTdata = new APPOINTMENTData();
           @override
              Widget build(BuildContext context) {
               return Card(
               color: Colors.greenAccent[50],
                child: ListTile(
                trailing: IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
                color: Colors.red,
                 onPressed: () {
                  showDialog(
                   context: context,
                 builder: (_) => new AlertDialog(
                  title: new Text("Are You Sure ?"),
                   actions: <Widget>[
                     FlatButton(
                        child: Text('cancel'),
                          onPressed: () {
                         Navigator.of(context).pop();
                            },
                           ),
                      ProgressButton(
                        color: Colors.red,
                       defaultWidget: Text('Delete'),
                      progressWidget: const CircularProgressIndicator(),
                        width: 70,
                        height: 40,
                        onPressed: () async {
                  await Future.delayed(
                      const Duration(milliseconds: 3000), () => 42);
                  await APPOINTMENTdata.deleteAPPOINTMENT(id).whenComplete(
                    () {
                      if (APPOINTMENTdata.status) {
                        showDialog(
                          context: context,
                          builder: (_) => new AlertDialog(
                            title: new Text(
                              "oops,please try again..!",
                              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
                            ),
                            actions: <Widget>[
                              FlatButton(
                                child: Text('ok'),
                                onPressed: () {
                                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                },
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        );
                      } else {
                        Navigator.of(context).pop();
                        Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
                          new SnackBar(
                            duration: const Duration(seconds: 15),
                            content: new Text('APPOINTMENT deleted !'),
                            backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                          ),
                        );
                      }
                    },
                  );
                  return () {
                    BlocProvider.of<NavigationBloc>(context).dispatch(
                      GoToAppoitmentHistoricalEvent(),
                    );
                  };
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    ),
            title: Row(
                children: [
                Text('Doctor:'),
                 SizedBox(width: 100),
                   Text(date),
                       ],
                      ),
                  subtitle: Text(
                    doctor,
               style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                   ),
                   ),
                 );
                  }
                }
```

Comment: "*I tried to setstate but still not working.*" What do you mean by "*still not working*"? You have a `StatelessWidget`, and these types of widgets do not have a `setState()` override because they're **stateless**. Have you tried implementing `setState()` in a `StatefulWidget`? I think that might solve your problem :)

Comment: I called the widget in statefulwidget  which has the future builder :)

Answer (score 0):

you should use a state manager. I suggest GetX.

https://pub.dev/packages/get

using getX you can make your list reactive so if anything change is the list, any the view will rebuild itself automatically.
for more detail about how it's done checkout the official documentation.

https://github.com/jonataslaw/getx/blob/master/documentation/en_US/state_management.md